# Removing records in a list with duplicate values

Tags: trigger, list

I wanted to remove records with duplicate Reporting_Year__c in a lost.

I have got the code and debug shows duplicate removed. but when I test I can see all records inc duplicate

```
list<Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c>  Uniquefcc = [Select id, Reporting_Year__c,Reporting_Year_End__c,
                                                           Achieved_Credits_in_Reporting_Yr_Funded__c,
                                                           Funded_Months__c, Contact__c,contact__r.FCC_Count__c
                                                           from Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c 
                                                           where Contact__c IN: updatedContId
                                                           Order by Reporting_Year__c];
    for(integer i=0;i<Uniquefcc.size();i++) {
             Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c fcci = Uniquefcc.get(i);

         for(integer j= i;j<Uniquefcc.size();j++) {
             Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c fccj = Uniquefcc.get(j); 
             if(fcci.Reporting_Year__c == fccj.Reporting_Year__c && i!=j) {
                 Uniquefcc.remove(j); 
                 system.debug('REMOVED::'+fcci.Reporting_Year__c);  
             }
         }
     }
    update Uniquefcc;

  system.debug('========final list=====' + Uniquefcc );
```

Comment: Using an O(n^2) algorithm has serious performance implications. You'll want to use a Map instead. That said, this algorithm should technically work. Also, comparing the entire record using == or != is a Bad Idea, as is using List.get, and repeated List.size calls. Finally, you're potentially skipping records, as you'd want to use `Uniquefcc.remove(j--);`

Comment: I used a map with a Date as Key as below

Comment: I used a map as the Date as Key and List as the value and trying to put the values in  the map then error thrown as Ill-legal assignment of sobject to List  Map<Date,Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c> UniqueMap = new Map<Date,Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c>();

Comment: this is how for(Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c newfcc: fccNewRd){
        list<Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c> listMap = UniqueMap.get(newfcc.Reporting_Year__c);
            if(listMap==Null){
                listMap = new List<Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c>();
                UniqueMap.put(newfcc.Reporting_Year__c, listMap);
            }
      listMap.add(newfcc);
    }

Comment: @JayWeera Is `Reporting_Year__c` unique field you are using to remove the duplicates?

Comment: @sfdcfox What do think about first about using an aggregate query with the HAVING clauses to get the duplicate Reporting_Year__c values. It would mean another query and loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to delete duplicate record then you have first find duplicate records and stored in list then delete all records from org..
Use following code to remove duplicate rec

```
list<Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c>  Uniquefcc = [Select id, Reporting_Year__c,Contact__c
                                           from Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c 
                                           where Contact__c IN: updatedContId
                                           Order by Reporting_Year__c];
```

map yearVsFCCRecordMap = new map();
list removeList = new list();
for(Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c FCCObj : Uniquefcc){

```
if(yearVsFCCRecordMap.containskey(FCCObj.Reporting_Year__c)){

    removeList.add(FCCObj);
}
else{

    yearVsFCCRecordMap.put(FCCObj.Reporting_Year__c, FCCObj);
}
```

}
if(removeList.size()>0){

```
database.delete(removeList, false);
```

}

Thank you,
Amol Salve
salesForce Developer

Comment: Sorry,  I got it wrong now I am having a compile error Incompatible value type Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c for Map<Date,List<Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c>> on the line yearVsFCCRecordMap.put(FCCObj.Reporting_Year__c, FCCObj); thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use set instead of list to remove duplicate or you can use

```
> map<integer,object>
```

so integer would be your Reporting_Year__c  and object would be your Contact__c

Answer (score 0):

You can remove duplicate record using Map .

Apex code:

```
Map<Date,Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c> objMap = new Map<Date,Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c>();

list<Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c>  Uniquefcc = [Select id, Reporting_Year__c,Reporting_Year_End__c,
                                                       Achieved_Credits_in_Reporting_Yr_Funded__c,
                                                       Funded_Months__c, Contact__c,contact__r.FCC_Count__c
                                                       from Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c 
                                                       where Contact__c IN: updatedContId
                                                       Order by Reporting_Year__c];


for(Funding_Cycles_Contacts__c FCC :Uniquefcc ){
    if(!objMap.containsKey(FCC.Reporting_Year__c)){
        objMap.put(FCC.Reporting_Year__c,FCC); 
    }

}
update objMap;
```